# how to manage url redirects in drupal 7

Tags: 7

My website is currently accessible via 2 address

www.mydomain.com
and 
mydomain.com

What is the best way to manage redirects. I would like

mydomain/blah to redirect to www.mydomain.com/blah

Answer (score 3):

I always use the vhost file for this:

```
# Enforce domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com(:.*)?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:.*?)(:.*)?$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I would much rather to this on the Apache level, than PHP, to keep it as fast a possible.

Similar configuration for nginx [here](http://aleksandarsavic.com/nginx-redirect-wwwexamplecom-requests-to-examplecom-or-vice-versa/).

Comment: The .htaccess file that comes with Drupal has already a rewrite rule for that.

Comment: Good point. I keep the rule in a separate vhost file though so I can easily version control it.

Answer (score 3):

You can open up the .htaccess file that's in the root directory of your Drupal install and uncomment the last two lines of this code snippet starting with RewriteCond and RewriteRule.

```
  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Right after this snippet in the .htaccess file, there's another couple of lines to uncomment if you wanted www.example.com to redirect to example.com.

Answer (score 1):

Looks at a redirect module like [301 redirect](http://drupal.org/project/domain_301_redirect), I have not tried it but the description seems to cover what you require.